# _mm_set_epi32 -- get stuck after some iteration

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing a server-client code in which client will send a 128 bit number and server return a different 128 bit number. But it get stuck after some iteration at a point where I am using **_mm_set_epi32** to combine 4 32 bit number to get a 128 bit number.

I am not able to understand what the problem is. Is it problem with networking or with some other because when I did the same thing on local machine then it works fine.

Here is the code for server :

```
    #include "allh.h"
#define SERV_TCP_PORT_A1 5035
struct data{
  __m128i num;
} recva1,recva2,senda1,senda2;

int main(){

  int socka1,newsocka1,clengtha1;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addra1,cli_addra1;
  char buffer[4096];
  socka1=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  serv_addra1.sin_family=AF_INET;
  serv_addra1.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
  serv_addra1.sin_port=htons(SERV_TCP_PORT_A1);
  printf("\nStart");
  bind(socka1,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addra1,sizeof(serv_addra1));
  printf("\nListening...");
  //printf("\n");
  listen(socka1,5);
  clengtha1=sizeof(cli_addra1);
  newsocka1=accept(socka1,(struct sockaddr*)&cli_addra1,&clengtha1);
  printf("Accepted  ===== B1");
  printf("\n");

  srand(time(NULL)); // randomize seed

  //int a=5,w=8,i=0;
  while(1){
    __m128i a,res;
    uint32_t *val;
    unsigned int a1,a2,a3,a4;
    a1 = rand();a2=rand();a3 = rand();a4 = rand();//
    a = _mm_set_epi32(a1,a2,a3,a4);

    read(newsocka1,&recva1,4096);
    printf("YO \n" );

    senda1.num = res;

    write(newsocka1,&senda1,4096);

  }
  return 0;`enter code here`
}
```

Here is my client code :

```
    #include "allh.h"
#define SERV_TCP_PORT_B1 5035
struct data{
  __m128i num;
} tosendb1,tosendb2,recvb1,recvb2;


int main(){
  int sockB1,sockB2;
  // declaring sockaddr_in
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addrb1,serv_addrb2;
  struct hostent *server;
  // configuring for b1
  sockB1=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  serv_addrb1.sin_family=AF_INET;
  serv_addrb1.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("10.0.0.2");
  serv_addrb1.sin_port=htons(SERV_TCP_PORT_B1);
  printf("\nReady for sending...\n");
  connect(sockB1,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addrb1,sizeof(serv_addrb1));

  uint64_t diffb1,diffb2;
  srand(time(NULL)); // randomizing seed with time
  // send the number after storing this in the buffer
  char buffer[4096];
  int count =0;
  for (count =0;count<1000000;count++){
    printf("%d\n",count );
    unsigned int b1=0,b2=0,b3=0,b4=0; // declaring 4 32 bit number to make one 128 bit number
    b1 = rand();b2=rand();b3 = rand();b4 = rand();// generate 4 random number
    printf("b1 %d\n",b1 );
    tosendb1.num = _mm_set_epi32(b1,b2,b3,b4);

    write(sockB1,&tosendb1,4096);
    printf("write\n");
    read(sockB1,&recvb1,4096);
    printf("recv\n" );
    //clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &endb1);   /* mark the end time */

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is allh.h :

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdint.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include<string.h>
#include <time.h>   /* for clock_gettime */
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <wmmintrin.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>
```

Comment: `_mm_set_epi32` is really inappropriate for this.

Comment: Can you suggest me something else for this.

Comment: By the way If I run both the code on same laptop then it works fine. It create problem when I use two different machine for sever and client.

Comment: Well it's not the problem, it's just pointless. `_mm_set_epi32` is for SIMD, you're just using it to store stuff to memory, which you could have done the normal way (ie one by one into an array).

Comment: I know that but I don't understand why this is not working. Please check this If you can.

Comment: `read(newsocka1,&recva1,4096);` I dont believe that `sizeof recva1` is 4096

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is the problem I am facing..